# How to provide an USB driver to have Windows automatically install it from the internet?

Tags: usb, installation, driver

For some USB devices, it seems that Windows can automatically locate and install a driver from the internet, when the device is attached for the first time. How can I provide this behaviour for my own USB device? Is there some way to register VID/PID of my device and assign a download URL for the driver?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the drivers are delivered through a mechanism called Windows Update.  I think you have to get your drivers certified by a Windows Hardware Quality Lab (WHQL).  This can cost a lot of money and I don't know much about it, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.